# Why am I listed as running a "tor exit node"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tor

I have a Google Compute Engine CentOS 7/Plesk Onyx server instance. Suddenly this morning I see via MXtoolbox.xom notification that my IP is listed in the "SECTOOR-EXITNODES" blacklist.

I looked up what a "tor exit node" is and can't even find this software running on my server, nor any config files.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Have you had it for very long? The previous user of the IP address may have been running an exit node.

Comment: I’ve had it since January, and have had this static IP from the beginning. I’ve had a daily blacklist check from mxtoolbox since the beginning too, and today it notified me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a temporary lapse in the sectoor.de DNSBL service.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8osmdw/ip_added_to_sectoor_exitnodes_blacklist_how_to/